# How do I convert this type of list with dictionary into a csv file?

Tags: python

I have a list such as bellow:

```
'jose-123': {'name': 'alex','age': '30', 'weight': 190},
'jose-124': {'name': 'mark','age: '20','weight': 180},
'jose-126': {'name': 'mark','age: '20','weight': 180},
'jose-125': {'name': 'mike','age': '50','weight': 49}
```

I want to convert it into a CSV file with python something like bellow:

| unit | name | age | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jose-123 | alex | 30 | 190 |
| jose-124 | mark | 20 | 180 |
| jose-126 | mark | 20 | 180 |
| jose-125 | mike | 50 | 49 |

Comment: Have a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.  You can loop over the data, create a list with the data you want for each row, then write it to the csv.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your post and show your code.

Comment: Is it actually a list? Because it looks like a dictionary, in which case you could easily use pandas to make a DataFrame, transpose and write to csv.

Comment: Is that the raw data? It looks like a dictionary with the outer braces missing.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel That's the raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your raw data is really how you show in your question, then you can wrap the said string in outer braces.

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd

raw = """\
'jose-123': {'name': 'alex','age': '30', 'weight': 190},
'jose-124': {'name': 'mark','age': '20','weight': 180},
'jose-126': {'name': 'mark','age': '20','weight': 180},
'jose-125': {'name': 'mike','age': '50','weight': 49}
"""
some_string = f"{{{raw}}}" # wrap in braces {}
d = ast.literal_eval(some_string)

temp = []
for k, v in d.items():
    a = {'unit': k}
    a.update(v)
    temp.append(a)

df = pd.DataFrame(temp)

print(df)
```

Comment: Note that I had to fix the quotes in your posted raw data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though its dictionary, containing sub-dictionaries.

In this case, you could easily go with pandas, convert into a DataFrame using

`df= pd.DataFrame(<YourList>)`

Then easily convert it into a csv using

`df.to_csv("filename.csv")`

Comment: I have tried this before and it doesn't work right. The problem is the data starts with 'jose-123': ... and that causes problem to not get the columns right.

Comment: So, you're saying that your raw data is a string without the outer braces that would make it a valid string representation of a dictionary?

Comment: From where are you getting said string?

Comment: That's correct. As you can see, the data starts with a string which causes problem. I don't know how to include that string as my first input. If I didn't have that string in the beginning I could do what you said but since there is a string before the dictionary starts, I don't know how to include that string as my first column entry.

Comment: You haven't said where (and how) the raw data is coming from. Perhaps there's another way that will give you an actual valid python object or a JSON string.

Comment: Why not make append your df columns headers as one of your rows in your data. Then reshape or transpose it perhaps?

Comment: @Sahil_Angra How would you do that?

Comment: Smth like , `temp = pd.DataFrame([df.columns], columns = df.columns)`, followed by `result = pd.concat([df, temp], ignore_index=True)` ? You can then transpose it to required format !